# Order by child and retrieve other child value

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following data set:

```
person-base 
{
     -K771quXhYWTo-F8oei9 
     {
        person: "Sam"
        value: 2
     }
     -K771uFngeQ6j0rvDhN_
    {
        person: "Joe"
        value: 1
    }
}
```

I am trying to retrieve the *value* of one of these keys based on it's *person* child.
I created a query that I'm using to point to the *person* value that matches the value of my *personName* variable (in this case "Sam") and so far, based on what I see in the console, it correctly retrieves the respective key and it's children.

My code:

```
var personRef = new Firebase("https://person-base.firebaseio.com/");
var personName = "Sam";

var query = personRef.orderByChild('person').equalTo(personName);
query.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
    console.log(snapshot.val().key()); // error 
});
```

My plan was to retrieve the parent key (generated by .push) that contains my *person* value and then to run something like the code I have below in order to retrieve *value*

```
personRef.child(key).on('value', function(childSnapshot) { 
   var obj = childSnapshot.val();
   console.log(obj.value);
});
```

However I am unable to retrieve the parent with my query.

My fiddle for further reference: https://jsfiddle.net/y20Lucyx/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you execute a query, the result is always a snapshot of all child nodes that match that query. Even though in your case there is only one matching child, you still need to handle the child with a loop:

```
query.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(sam) {
      console.log(sam.val());
      console.log(sam.key());
    });
});
```